# pandas plotting 2 dataframes with same column names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 2 dataframes, containing same indexes and same column names (10 columns
For example:
from df1

```
   A  B  C
1  0  4  8
2  5  6  9
3  2  5  1
```

from df2:

```
   A  B  C
1  9  4  5
2  1  4  2
3  5  5  1
```

I want to plot on the same graph, column A from df1 vs column A from df2, column B from df1 vs column B from df2, etc..and this for every column.
how could I do that with pandas and matplotlib

Comment: What kind of plot you are looking at?

Comment: just simple lines. I am plotting some ratio vs temperatures.
I want to know how I can iterate on the whole set of columns and not write code for plotting for each pairs independantly

Comment: Do you want bar charts?

Comment: No thanks I needed lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `df1` and `df2` be your dataframes you could use the below code which loops over all columns and saves the plots for you as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd    
for column in df1.columns:
        x = df1[column]
        y = df2[column]

        if len(x) != len(y):
            x_ind = x.index
            y_ind = y.index
            common_ind = x_ind.intersection(y_ind)
            x = x[common_ind]
            y = y[common_ind]

        plt.scatter(x,y)
        plt.savefig("plot" +column+".png")
        plt.clf()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: seems great but I have an issue. my x and y don't have the same size. for some data in y I don't have values in x. what should I do? is there a way to remove from y indexes that don't exist in x?

Comment: I have added a condition which checks if the size is same or not, if not then it will only pick only those indices which are common.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the way to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = {'A':[0,5,2],'B':[4,6,5],'C':[8,9,1]}
d2 = {'A':[9,1,5],'B':[4,4,5],'C':[5,2,1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

df1_a = df1['A'].tolist()
df1_b = df1['B'].tolist()
df2_a = df2['A'].tolist()
df2_b = df2['B'].tolist()

plt.plot(df1_a, df1_b, 'r') 
plt.plot(df2_a, df2_b, 'b') 
plt.show()
```